# test if inputted number is a triangular number

Tags: java, math

I need to create a program to test if a given number inputted by the user is a triangular number.

I have created a script that just gives the list of all the triangular numbers, but in this program the user needs to enter a number and the program will have to determine whether that number is triangular or not.

Comment: [Wikipedia on triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)

Answer (score 11):

Since the wikipedia article you refer to state that

`An integer x is triangular if and only if 8x + 1 is a square`

You can of course make the square check a bit faster, but this can solve it:

```
public static boolean isTriangularNumber(long num) {
     long calc_num = 8*num+1;
     long t = (long) Math.sqrt(calc_num);
     if (t*t==calc_num) {
        return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Does this mean the same as "Forall x, if 8x+1 is a square, then x is triangular"?

Comment: Forall triangular numbers, it holds that 8x+1 is a square. But couldn't there be other numbers where the same holds? I think one must compute the triangular root and check if it is an integer.

Comment: I'm no expert on triangular numbers, but I tested all up to 1000, and they're correctly checked.

Answer (score 3):

I think this probably represents the spirit of the assignment.

```
public void isTriangular(int input)
{
   int currentTriNum = 0;
   int n=0; 

   while (currentTriNum < input)
   {
     currentTriNum += n; 
     n++; 
   }

   if (currentTriNum != input) 
      System.out.println("This is NOT a triangular number");
   else 
      System.out.println("This is a triangular number"); 


}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Triangular numbers** are a pattern of numbers that form *equilateral triangles*.
Each subsequent number in the sequence adds a new row of dots to the triangle as in example:

[image: First_six_triangular_numbers]

Knowing that if `8 * n + 1` is a square number, then `n` must be a triangular number, the method the corresponding method looks as:

```
public static boolean isTriangular(int number) {
    double val = (Math.sqrt(8 * number + 1) - 1) / 2;
    return val % 1 == 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have the list of triangular numbers, you can search an initail segement of that for the given number, until you find the number or a triangular number that is greater than the gien one.

This algorithm would be O(n).

But you could do better with a binary search. For this, choose a lower bound of 0 and an upper bound k where Tk > n. Then check T(k/2). If n is T(k/2), n is triangular. If n is greater, set the lower bound to k/2 + 1 else set the upper bound to k/2. Repeat while the lower bound is smaller than or equal the upper bound.

Even better, compute the triangular root and check if it is an integer:

```
// check to see if x is atriangular number
let a = 8*x + 1
if a is not a square number x is not triangular
let b = sqrt(a)
let n = (b-1) / 2
if n is not an integer x is not triangle
otherwise, it is the n-th triangle
```