# While/if Loop is not working in class

Tags: class, if-statement, while-loop

I'm learning java and I'm having an issue with my `if` code not running.

In the following code I'm trying to determine if a number (variable `num`) is a triangle number (1,3, 6, 10 etc).  The code should run through and give the "Is Triangle".  However it keeps spitting out Null.

I understand this is not the most effective way to do this code, but I am trying to learn how to use Classes.

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    class NumberShape {
        int num = 45;
        int tri = 0;
        int triplus = 0;
        String triresult;

        public String triangle() {

            while (tri < num) {
                if (tri == num) {
                    triresult =  "Is a Triangle";
                    System.out.println("Is a Triangle");
                } else if (tri + (triplus + 1) > num){
                    triresult =  "Is Not a Triangle";
                } else {
                    triplus++;
                    tri = tri + triplus;
                }
            }
            return triresult;
        }
    }

    NumberShape result = new NumberShape();
    System.out.println(result.triangle());
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Maybe this can help you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493483/test-if-inputted-number-is-a-triangular-number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
            class NumberShape {
                int num = 10;//Try other numbers
                int tri = 0;
                int triplus = 0;
                int res = 0;
                String triresult =  "Is Not a Triangle";

                int[] tab= new int[num];



                public String triangle() {

                    //to calculate the triangle numbers 
                     for(int i = 0; i<num; i++){
                         res = res + i;
                         tab[i]=res;
                     }

                     //To check if num is a triangle or not
                     for(int i = 0; i<tab.length; i++){
                         System.out.println(">>  " + i + " : " + tab[i]);
                         if(tab[i]== num){
                             triresult =  num + " Is a Triangle";
                             break;//Quit if the condition is checked
                         }else{
                             triresult =  num + " Is Not a Triangle";
                         }
                     }

                    return triresult;
                }
            }

            NumberShape result = new NumberShape();
            System.out.println(result.triangle());
            }
}
```

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

Step through the loop carefully.  You'll probably see that there is a case where

```
(tri < num)
```

fails, and thus you fall out of the loop, while

```
(tri == num)
```

and

```
(tri + (triplus + 1) > num)
```

both fail too, so no text gets set before you fall out.

You probably want to do your if-tests within the method on just tri, not a modification of tri, so as to reduce your own confusion about how the code is working.