# Solving problems with the shortest length of coding

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a problem whose problem content is shown below:

> John is into playing with marbles, and he wants to build an isosceles right triangle with the number of marbles he's already had. The isosceles right triangle is a triangle that has two sides that have an equal length. However, John has no idea whether the number of marbles he has can build this triangle or not. Please check for him and give him a result.

[image]

> For example in this picture, if the number of marbles he has is 6 so he can build his own isosceles right triangle with the length of its side is 3.

Actually, the algorithm for this problem is not difficult. But the requirement is that I need to solve it in the shortest length of coding. For details, my coding does not exceed the length of 100 characters, which contains the length of the function's name (42 characters for the function's name). It implies that your coding just contains at most 58 characters

Note:

- "characters" here do not contain spaces, tabs, and newlines.
- If the number of marbles is 0 or 1, the result must be false, not true.
- Range of input is 0 <= marb <= 10^15
- Time limit: 0.1s for C++
- The given function's name is `bool checkAngledAndIsosceles(long long marb)`

Here is my algorithm if there is no limit in coding's character:

```
bool checkAngledAndIsosceles(long long marb)
{
    if(marb <= 1) return false;
    else
    {
        int i = 1;
        while(marb > 0)
        {
            marb -= i;
            i++;
        }
        if(marb == 0) return true;
        else return false;
    }   
}
```

The algorithm here is that the number of marbles must be a sum of arithmetic progression. However, this coding is too long so I still need to reduce my code.

Comment: What is your question? You mentioned the algorithm is not difficult so I assume you have implemented it and are just having trouble reducing the code. You should post that code here.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Oh I forgot it, I will edit my question

Comment: @Scotty If you can beam up your code we might have a better chance to find improvements.

Comment: I have updated my coding. You all please give me some advices

Comment: @JesperJuhl This is just my coding in case there is no limit in characters. To satisfy its requirement, it needs to reduce much much more than that. Even in the way you solve this problem

Comment: @Scotty could you post the link of this question?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you just need to check if a number is triangular with the extra stipulation that 0 and 1 are excluded.

```
bool checkAngledAndIsosceles(long long marb)
{
    long long x = 8 * marb + 1, s = sqrt(x);
    return marb > 1 && s * s == x;
}
```

I found the formula I used here: [test if inputted number is a triangular number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493483/test-if-inputted-number-is-a-triangular-number)

Comment: Luckily, there is just only one case getting wrong. I feel so confused here

Answer (score 0):

Noting that `(1 + 2 + 3 ... + N) == N * (N+1) /2` any number that is an answer should fit in the above formula (also not counting 0 or 1). you can use this to construct something like this:

```
auto i = 2;
for (; i*i + i < 2 * marb; i++);
return i * i + i == 2 * marb ? 1 : 0;
```

to save even more characters you might be able to return 0 or 1 if you compiler allows.

**Note** that this won't cover the whole `long long` range. Sorry, couldn't get closer than this. This is generally a pretty weird problem. Like why do you have no control over the name of the function if you are constrained on the length of the code?

Comment: I don't know why but your coding always return true

Comment: my bad. I missed the name of input is marb and it is a long long.
Another issue, do you need long long for the type of input? if yes, this won't work.
unless you are allowed to use macros or typdefs outside of the function?

Comment: Actually, even when I use long long for ``i``, it gets wrong on 5/20 hidden test cases. Can you figure it out?

Comment: it is most likely because of the wraparound on large numbers, i.e. i*i + i become too big and wraps around. editted the answer

Comment: I think that the reason for that is when I run the program from 1 to a really big number, it gets too long. Therefore, it is killed when it reaches the limit executing time. Can you help me to find another way which is better than this?

Comment: For example, as I give the number ``15821192824747`` it takes so much time while my limited time is 0.1s